# Detect commits that change white space or comments

Tags: git, repository, github-api

Is there any way to detect either each changed line of code in each commit is real or fake(changes in white space or comments)?
Is there any way to determine either the commit submit fake(white space or comments) changes or not?
Indeed, I want to filter out the commits that submit fake changes( white space and comments) among all commits of a repository. Besides, I need to detect files and related line of code with real changes and files with fake(comments and white space) changes in each commit.

Comment: Perhaps not an exact answer, but many IDEs (such as IntelliJ or Eclipse) can report to you using a diff whether a file has any differences beyond just whitespace changes.

Comment: I need an automatic approach, because I need to check all commits of repository which can be more than 10,000